# Is there a way to add a link to a network folder?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that runs a build. If build finishes sucessfully, it create a folder in the network with the installer package (it is not located in Job's workspace).
Is there a away to add a link to this installer package folder?

I've tried using Description Setter Plugin and Rich text publisher, link appears but nothing happens when pressing it.

** With a custom HTML page it works.

Comment: where do you expect the link appears?

Comment: It should be related to the job. And needs to appear only when job is finished successfully.